# Search with Textbox and Drop Down menus - php mysql html phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

How can i make query to filter not only by one field like this

```
select * from table1 where LOWER(A) like LOWER('%$A%')
```

but to filter also from drop down menu values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another filter condition in your where clause.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE a LIKE '%$A%'
AND some_other_field = 'some dropdown value'
```

By the way, if you use a case-insensitve collation on field "A", then there is no need to cast the values to lower cases as the comparison would be case-insensitive (this is why I have removed the calls to `LOWER()` in my example.  Your default MySQL setting is most likely case-insensitive, so check it out.  By not casting to lower case, you case still use an index on field "A" to speed up the search.

Comment: its case sensitive thats why i put there LOWER(). and how do i put 'some drop down value' there if the values are dynamical, is there a way to put all <select> by id to query or something like that?

Comment: @eLbor Did you not read my comment about there being no need to cast to lower case in order to do a case-insensitive search?  By casting both to lower you are performing a case-insensitive search, but also losing the ability to use your index on the field.  Just use case-insensitive collation on the field (which it probably already is anyway).  I just used an placeholder example of 'some dropdown value".  When building your query, you would just need to replace this value with the value POSTed to the page from the dropdown.